# Find those entries in numpy array bigger than input datetime

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to get that entries of an datetime numpy array back that are bigger then my input datetime variable.

Unfortunately, I get this error when executing the code below:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
myRange = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=5, freq='1D20min')

myArray = np.array(myRange).astype(np.datetime64).reshape(-1,1)
print("myArray:", myArray)
myDatetime = pd.datetime(2018,4,10,2,59,59)

myArray[myArray>myDatetime]
```

.

```
myArray: [['2018-04-09T00:00:00.000000000']
 ['2018-04-10T00:20:00.000000000']
 ['2018-04-11T00:40:00.000000000']
 ['2018-04-12T01:00:00.000000000']
 ['2018-04-13T01:20:00.000000000']]
```

Comment: you are trying to use boolean indexing, but the syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is around comparing: 
myArray (of type np.datetime64) with 
myDateTime (of type pd.datetime)

Changing myDateTime to a numpy datetime64 gives a result.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
myRange = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=5, freq='1D20min')

myArray = np.array(myRange).astype(np.datetime64).reshape(-1,1)
print("myArray:", myArray)
myDatetime = np.datetime64("2018-04-10T02:59:59")

myArray[myArray>myDatetime]
```

gives:

```
myArray: [['2018-04-09T00:00:00.000000000']
['2018-04-10T00:20:00.000000000']
['2018-04-11T00:40:00.000000000']
['2018-04-12T01:00:00.000000000']
['2018-04-13T01:20:00.000000000']]
Out[27]: 
array(['2018-04-11T00:40:00.000000000', 
       '2018-04-12T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-04-13T01:20:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```